# На странице размещены 5+ блоков, состоящих из текстового поля и поля ввода типа checkbox.В текстовые поля вводить только числа

Tags: javascript, html

На странице размещены 5+ блоков, состоящих из текстового поля и поля ввода типа checkbox. В текстовые поля вводить только числа.
При нажатии кнопки, проверить корректность введенных данных, если есть ошибки уведомить пользователя через alert.

Кроме этого сформировать массив из числовых значений, с условием, если в соответствующем блоке checkbox активный, в массив записывается число в два раза меньше входное.
Вывести сформирован массив в абзац.

```js
let form = document.forms.test;
let text = form.querySelectorAll('[type=text]');
let checkbox = form.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  let result = [];
  event.preventDefault();
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    let value = text[i].value;
    if (value === '') {
      continue;
    };
    let regexp = /^\d+$/;
    if (!regexp.test(value)) {
      alert('Неверное значение:' + value);
      continue;
    };
    if (checkbox[i].checked) {
      result.push(value / 2);
    };
  };
  form.result.value = result;
});
```

```html
<form name="test">
  Значения<br>
  <input type="text"><input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="text"><input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="text"><input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="text"><input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="text"><input type="checkbox"><br> Результат:
  <br>
  <input name="result"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Получить результат">
</form>
```

Comment: Вроде бы, всё работает. Не понятно, в чем вопрос...

Comment: как вывести сформирован массив в абзац?

Comment: В каком формате должен быть результат?